# How can I generate some phrases from a knowledge base after DCG?

Tags: prolog, dcg, nlg

I have defined my grammar in prolog as DCG (Definite Clause Grammar).
Now I want to generate some phrases according with the facts present in my knowledge base.
For example, if I have `likes(mark, julia).` I want to generate the sentence

> Mark likes Julia.

How can I do this?

Comment: `print_phrase(Verb) :- call(Verb, X, Y), write(X), write(' '), write(Verb), write(Y), write('.'), nl.` and you can call, `print_phrase(like).` Or better, use mat's answer and then write a simple recursive rule to write the sentence/list out nicer. If you want to capitalize the names, you'll need to dig into the atom/char processing predicates. As a beginner, you should browse the Prolog predicate documentation and play with some of the promising looking ones.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We must take into account that `likes/2` is a normal Prolog predicate, *not* a DCG.

Hence, we use **`{}//1`** to refer to regular Prolog predicates *within* DCGs.

For example:

```
sentence -->
        [X, likes, Y],
        { likes(X, Y) }.
```

Sample usage:

```
?- phrase(sentence, Ls).
Ls = [mark, likes, julia].
```